# Updating sub panel in shed

Tags: electrical

The sub panel in my shed(about 75ft run from main panel)is very outdated and gfci breakers aren't available for it so I want to update the panel as gfci are required for pool equipment.
The panel has 220v and currently has 2 tandem 15amp breakers powering 4 outlets and 3 lights and one double pole 20amp breaker powering the pool pump. Their used to be a pool heater but since has been removed. The supply from the main panel for this sub panel is on a 50 amp double pole breaker. Their is not a bare copper grounding wire ran to the sub panel either and I would like to add one

My questions:
Will a 60 amp subpanel be sufficient? If so will the 50 amp double pole breaker in the main panel need to be changed?
Would it be nearly impossible to run a bare 10ga ground wire through the existing pvc conduit that is run underground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to upgrade the supply breaker.

The sub-panel can be any size 50 amps or up. Sub-panel "size" is more about space than amperage, at any point past "at least as big as the supply" and space is a good thing to have which normally does not cost much.

It's often worth comparing the price of basic "main" panels that move in volume (100A, 200A) to the cost of a sub-panel which are sometimes MORE expensive, because they sell a lot less of them, or they cost a trivial amount less.

It's perfectly fine to feed a 100A(or whatever) main breaker from a 50 A breaker - the 100A breaker will be serving as a disconnect switch, and you will remove the bonding screw in that panel so it IS a sub-panel. Then you'll have plenty of space for anything.

In most cases the best way to add a wire in existing conduit (unless someone left you a pull string, and sometimes even then) is to pull out the wires in it now (and use them to pull in a pulling rope as you do), add the new wire, and pull all the wires back in together. Green insulated may be a better choice than bare for your grounding wire; Among other considerations, stranded pulls a lot easier than solid.

In the new sub-panel with a 4-wire feed, you'll keep the grounds and neutrals isolated (removal of the bond screw and using a separate bar for grounding connections) and you will either tie the grounds into the grounding electrode system the shed (as a separate structure) should already have had, or add that and bond it to your ground as well.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the information.        Any tips on fishing an additional bare wire thru the underground conduit?

Comment: As stated, pull out all the wires in there now, add the new wire, and pull them all back in, unless there is a pull-string in with the wires you have now. Ramming a fish-tape through there is going to be miserable and might damage your existing wires to boot.

Comment: Ok thanks again. That was an idea I had just wasn't sure if it was the best way to go about it. The conduit is 1 inch and the current wires are 6 ga.  It seems like it might be a tight fit to get them back in but other than digging it all up their isnt another way.

Comment: You'll be 20-25% fill which is not bad, as pulls go. Max fill is 40% and I avoid that like the plague (i.e. I'll upsize conduit to stay at a lower fill percentage.) You can pick up a quart of pulling lube if you like, it might make things easier, but is often not needed, and it's messy.

Comment: What size rope would you recommend? Also what is the best way to tie the 4 wires to the ropes while keeping the knots as small as possible?

Comment: Do not TIE. Lumpy knots are evil. 1/4 or 3/8" hollow braided poly is a good choice. You can expand the hollow braid and slip all 4 wires inside the rope, for a good distance (a foot or more) and then you tape the rope to the cables. The braid being pulled helps to hold the cables inside it, the tape keeps the rope from sliding off them. Use quality electrical tape, and clean off the wires you had to backpull before taping to them.

Comment: If using rope you cannot expand, tape it to the wires for a good long distance  and use tape to make the end smooth and tapering - also helps to shift each wire back a few inches from the next so that the whole mass has more of a taper on the front end. Or they make wire braid pulling attachments, but that's a bit special-purpose for your one-time job.

Comment: You've been very helpful and I feel more confident in getting this done with your tips. I'd also like to add a disconnect at the house before the wiring goes under ground. Should I use a non fusible or fusible disconnect? What size fuse should it be if go the latter route?

Comment: Seems like overkill - you already have a 50A breaker in the main panel which is a disconnect, and "fused" (or current-limited, anyway) - if you really see the **need for** or **use of** a second disconeect on the house side, there's no obvious need for it to be a fused one, since it is already fed by a breaker. But there's also no obvious (to me) reason not to simply shut off the breaker if you want it disconnected at the house side...